# Armadillo Sparse Matrix CSC - How to store zero value

Tags: c++, matrix, julia, sparse-matrix, armadillo

Armadillo (C++ linear algebra library : http://arma.sourceforge.net/) support a preliminary version of Sparse Matrix (in CSC storing model). As I read in the documentation and the code, **the armadillo sparse matrix implementation does not differentiate between zero values and "unset" values.**

The documentation says that all the value stored are non-zero, by deduction all non-stored values are zero. Instead what I need is to distinguish "unset" from zero.

I currently port a Julia project to C++/Armadillo where I need to manipulate some sparses matrices with -1, 0, 1 and "unset" values. In contrast to armadillo, Julia distinguishes zero and "unset" in its sparse matrix implementation.

My first idea is maybe to use complex sparse matrix (arma::sp_cx_mat, arma::sp_cx_imat) with little tricks to manage simili-zero values (exploit the imaginary as dummy non-zero part). But this is really non-elegant and surely impact the code performance.

Do you think there's a way to bypass the Armadillo limitation without write my own matrix class?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: This is probably not supported (but i'm just guessing) as this is a popular design-decision even done within Matlab. Maybe it would be better to analyze the julia-code to reason about the needing for this kind of usage and maybe change the original sparse-matrix usage.

Comment: The julia code is needed to generate topological matrix of a electronic circuit by using is incidence matrix. The julia algorithm, in few words, is a shifting/permutation of the incidence matrix (+/- 1) where 0 is a special case in the range (-1 to +1). Modifying this function require a deep refactoring of a large number of other part of the framework.

Julia manage non-zero values in two way : the non-zeros values (all the values stored in the matrix) and the true non-zeros values (all the values stored in the matrix except the zero stored).

Comment: Without too much knowledge, the basic question is just: what are they gaining? Most of the time this explicit-zero usage is just for performance (as resetting something to zero can be expensive). So there is no algorithmic problem to use classic sparse-matrices, although it might be slower. But of course you are right, that there might be a lot hidden in the code. I think there were some heavy discussions about nnz and co.; how it should behave with these explicit zeros. This would make porting hard.

Comment: In a sparse matrix all the values are initiated to zero, so just don't set the zero values? If you read a non-set value from a sparse matrix it should return zero (as opposed to `not set`).

Comment: @Svaberg - no. Julia sparse matrix logic don't initialize the matrix to zero value. Julia is "not-set" based, and the set values are zero or not. With Armadillo, the sparse matrix is zero-initialized, so it's impossible for me to retrieve the setted values that can be [-1, 0, 1] in a particular algorithm that shift value around this range.

Comment: @MaximeCoorevits I see what you mean after looking at the julia documentation. It is the julia implementation that is non-standard. Your question says _Armadillo don't allow to store zero-value in is sparse matrices_. This does not really make sense, support for "storing" zero values will never be added to armadillo. A matrix of real numbers is a mathetmatical object and cannot have "unset" values.

Comment: @Svaberg - you're right, my sentence is ambigous. And for sure, this is not an  lack of feature of Armadillo but a Julia particular implementation. Thank you for taking the time to try to help me.

Comment: @MaximeCoorevits No problem! I would proceed by using an armadillo matrix of integers i.e. `int8`. As you are only interested in (-1,0,1,unset) you can use any value that is not (-1,0,1) as the unset value?

Comment: @Svaberg - Yes, but I need to rewrite the algorithm that is playing around the negativity and positivity (shifting values). So adding an temporary offset is a bad idea that break the algorithm logic. My idea is to port the code, not rewrite it. I work slowly on this subject, maybe other part of the framework will stop me, so I wait and see.